# Distribution build of Finch demo ends with GCC error

Tags: iphone, xcode, finch

thanks to zoul for sharing his openal avaudioplayer alternative!!  its exactly what i needed,

heres my problem.. i cant build a distribution build w/o getting
general gcc-4.2 failed with error code 1,

i built my code within the finch demo project and figured it might be
something i did.

so i re-downloaded demo... duplicated release, renamed distribution
and same thing...

know what im missing?

thanks!!

---

built clean finch demo in device 3.0 distribution, 
it works for device debug so i think codesigning is ok

-
here is the error code:

```
ProcessPCH /var/folders/vB/vBGLPzEOHIaZaBe67EuRZU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Demo_Prefix-dhjhmgdrpwujnmakgukffcldlmim/Demo_Prefix.pch.gch Demo_Prefix.pch normal armv6 objective-c com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd /Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x objective-c-header -arch armv6 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -mdynamic-no-pic -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.3.sdk -fvisibility=hidden -gdwarf-2 -mthumb -miphoneos-version-min=3.1.3 -iquote /Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/Demo-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/Demo-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/Demo-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/Demo-project-headers.hmap -F/Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Release-iphoneos -I/Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/DerivedSources/armv6 -I/Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/build/Demo.build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.build/DerivedSources -c /Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/Demo_Prefix.pch -o /var/folders/vB/vBGLPzEOHIaZaBe67EuRZU+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Demo_Prefix-dhjhmgdrpwujnmakgukffcldlmim/Demo_Prefix.pch.gch

arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/giles73/Downloads/zoul-Finch-a97b909-1/Demo/Demo_Prefix.pch: No such file or directory
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: warning: '-x objective-c-header' after last input file has no effect
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, my fault, that’s a bug. Wrong prefix header setting in the Release build mode. Fixed, thank you. To fix your project: right-click your target, select Get Info, switch to the Build tab, set Configuration to All Configurations, search for Prefix Header and set it to `prefix.pch`.